# How to add a column which represents a list of objects

Tags: java, mysql

I want to create a class (which maps to a table in a MySQL databse) in java and it has the following members:

```
id (int)
policyNumber (string)
cost (double)
beneficiaries (list of Beneficiary objects)
```

And the `Beneficiary` class has the following members:

```
name (string)
gender (enum with Male or Female as possible values)
dateOfBirth (Date)
```

How would I create a column in my table that would represent a list of `Beneficiary` objects?

Comment: I don't know what 'cost' represents but I will observe that things to do with money are normally decimal; it's pretty much why decimal was invented.

Comment: @Strawberry how would i specify in my java application that the 'cost' member is decimal?

Comment: I was referring to the table, not the class, but apologies if that wasn't clear

Comment: @Strawberry just to be sure, does that mean that jpa/hibernate will know how to map a double from my java app to a decimal in mysql?

Comment: Not knowing anything about those technologies, I really couldn't say.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding a field to `Beneficiary` table/class that maps to the `id` of the previous one (e.g. `policy_id`)

(or use a mapping table if it's a many-to-many relationship)

Comment: The fact that it's called `beneficiaries` slightly suggests one scenario is more likely than the other